# set Value is not working with useformcontext using react-hook-form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to set Value on page loads for select and textfield, its not working. its working fine for textfield but not for selectfield

Select

```
const RHFSelect = ({name, options, defaultValue}) =>{
 const {register, unregister,formState: { errors }} = useFormContext();
return ( 

 <Select  multiple={multiple ?? false} {...register(name)}
  defaultValue={defaultValue ?? []} > 
        {options && options?.map((ele, index) => (
<MenuItem key={index} value={ele.value}>{ele.label}</MenuItem>
  ))}
      </Select> )}
```

Texfield is working fine

```
const RHFTextField = ({name, defaultValue}) =>{
 const {register, unregister,formState: { errors }} = useFormContext();
return ( <TextField   {...register(name)} defaultValue={defaultValue ?? ""}/>)
}
```

parentcomponent

```
const ParentComponent= () =>{
const sizes = [{label:'Small', value='small'}, {label:'Medium', value='Medium'}]
const methods = useForm();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = methods;

 useEffect(() => {
  setValue("purchasedPrice", 100)
 setValue("size", "Medium")
  }, [])
return ( 
 <FormProvider {...methods}>
 <RHFTextField name="purchasedPrice" />
<RHFSelect options={sizes}  name="size" defaultValue={[]} />
 </FormProvider>)
}
```

Comment: An array of size objects seems to be incorrect.
const sizes = [{label:'Small', value:'small'}, {label:'Medium', value:'Medium'}]

Comment: Also, defaultValue should not be any empty array instead it should be one of the values of the options defaultValue={"Medium"}

Comment: its not working with Mui Select, normal select is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Material UI you can use the following select component that is using the controller wrapper around the select.

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormControl, FormHelperText, MenuItem, TextField, TextFieldProps} from '@mui/material';
import {Controller, useFormContext} from 'react-hook-form';
import {FC} from 'react';

type IFormInputProps = {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  handleChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  emp?: string;
  options: {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  }[];
  // defaultValue?: string;
} & TextFieldProps;

const FormSelectBox: FC<IFormInputProps> = ({
  name,
  label,
  handleChange,
  options,
  defaultValue = '',
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const {
    control,
    formState: {errors}
  } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <TextField
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            select
            label={label}
            error={!!errors[name]}
            {...otherProps}
            value={value}
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
              onChange(e);
              if (handleChange) handleChange(e);
            }}>
            {options.map(option => (
              <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
          <FormHelperText error={!!errors[name]}>
            {String(errors[name] ? errors[name]?.message : '')}
          </FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  );
};
export default FormSelectBox;
```

Use this component in your Form

```
import FormSelectBox from "FormSelectBox";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const sizes = [
    { label: "Small", value: "small" },
    { label: "Medium", value: "medium" },
  ];
  const methods = useForm();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = methods;

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue("purchasedPrice", 100);
    setValue("size", "medium");
  }, []);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <RHFTextField name="purchasedPrice" />
      <FormSelectBox options={sizes} name="size" defaultValue={"small"} />
    </FormProvider>
  );
};
```